# Ajuda Loader Oracle - Campo variavel

Tags: pl-sql

Preciso fazer o loader de um arquivo `.txt` com vários registros para uma tabela.

Porém esta tabela contém um campo (`Seq`) que não existe no arquivo de texto e este campo deverá sempre ser `1` e `2`. Por ex.: o primeiro registro importado será marcado como `1`, o segundo como `2`, o terceiro como `1`, o quarto como `2`, o quinto como `1`, assim por diante.

Me deram a ideia de fazer isso usando `for` e `if`, mas não consegui.

Segue o comando do Loader:

```
load data

infile '/home/oracle/dados1.txt'

badfile '/home/oracle/exemplo3.bad'

discardfile '/home/oracle/exemplo3.dsc'

truncate

into table produtos

fields terminated by ","

( codigo, nome, seq, data_inclusao )
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma variável e inicializar ela como 1. No insert adiciona ela, após o insert faz uma checagem e modifica ela:

```
if variavel == 1 then 
   variavel := 2 
else 
   variavel := 1 
endif
```

Espero ter ajudado.